# android - equivalent of "a name" html tag in textview

Tags: android, textview

I was wondering if there was the equivalent of  and  in an android textview? For instance, if you had a long piece of text with various subheadings so that you could go from a link in the contents to the relevant section of the view in the main body of the text?

(btw, I know the "name" tag is deprecated, but I put it here just for discussion)

Answer (score -3):

If you want to show long text then use,
1. Multiline textview.
2. Single line textview with ellipsis and marquee effect.

Comment: Long text is not the problem.